# Betfair Non-interactive Login does not work

Tags: c#, api, authentication, certificate, betfair

I have been struggling to achieve Non-interactive login to Betfair using certificate.
I'm using C# and on Windows 10.
I'm just testing with sample project:
https://github.com/betfair/API-NG-sample-code

- I have app key
- I created certificates with no password following the url:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N-EnnmN59Y&t=51s
- I uploaded the *.crt to my account and it's like:
  [image]
  [image]
- Next according to the note from the sample, I created *.pfx for P12.
  https://github.com/betfair/API-NG-sample-code/blob/master/loginCode/Non-interactive-cSharp/README.md

So I think everything is done in right order but it keeps saying internal error.
[image]

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everyone.
Sorry, there was misunderstanding.
The login process asks password during running and I thought it's for the password of certificate.
But now I see that it's the password for an account of Betfair.
If anyone spent time because of my stupid question, sorry.

I decided to post this as an answer hoping others not misunderstand the flow.

Thanks.